# What is the difference between electric current and electric charge?

Tags: electricity

Are electric current and electric charge the same thing? I'm just getting back into relearning chemistry, so a more in-depth answer about how electricity works in general would be wonderful.

Edit: Thank you all for clarifying that this belongs to the Physics SE. That being said, I guess this question doesn't have much relevance to me anymore. I'm honestly not sure if I should delete the question or not, so I'll leave that up to the mods to decide. Thanks again.

Comment: I think this should go on physics SE. The question itself seems too broad imo (basically you're asking about the whole of electrostatics). You might find the MIT 8.02 lectures by Walter Lewin good, just watch as much or as little as you need. The materials are not hosted on MIT any more since Lewin got sacked for online sexual harassment last December, but they are available on other places online (just Google for it), and regardless of what he did to his students his lectures were very, very good.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I think this question is indeed very broad and it will most likely be too broad for physics as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Physics.SE.

Comment: I don't think it should be migrated if it's gonna be closed as *too broad* there too. Since the author isn't interested in their question, I dunno what else we could do. But migrating isn't an option.

Comment: Electric charge is a bus. Electric current is a bus that is driving somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad. The first thing. No they are not the same. Simple explanation for these terms can be:
Charge: Its the "amount" of unbalanced electricity in a body.  Its usually measured in the form of electrons (either excess or deficiency). Its units is coulomb.
Current: It is the "flow" of electrons from higher electric potential towards the lower. Its unit is ampere.

To visualize how they are not the same is by considering two situations (without going into any calculations). Two bodies (A & B) are connected via some copper wire. A has 1 million Coulombs charge & the second one has 1million & 1 coulombs charge. Now individually these charges are enormous, but as the difference between the two is only 1 coulomb, its a very low difference in charge, so a little current will flow between them.

Now if you change the bodies' charge. A has 100 Coulombs & B has 10 .. much more current will flow between the bodies, because there is a way bigger potential difference.

ps. and yes its a physics questions.

Comment: edit: error, sorry. wrong post.